# Ajax Toolkit Editor in ListView does not render toolbars

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am attempting to use the Ajax Toolkit's HTML Editor in a ListView, but unfortunately it's not rendering the toolbars when I do.  It actually appears that the Javascript simply isn't initializing.  If I move the editor tag outside of the ListView on the same page it works.

```
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstValues">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ContentControlAttributeUID") %>'
                        ID="hidAttributeUID" />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContentControlAttributeName") %>' />
                </th>
                <td>

                    <ajaxToolkit:Editor ID="htmlValue" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="800px"/>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

IE reports the following error:

```
Webpage error details
```

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; HPNTDF; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 13 Aug 2010 18:18:36 UTC

Message: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: elements
Line: 4868
Char: 12
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:53791/ScriptResource.axd?d=-CwDSaVoJV5wizpX17LGeWO_begkXaYUs_-h1AdeNqc_WMOXUiDMagM5BMZHVvgp0&t=ffffffffbd2983fc

Comment: What does the error in the browser say?

Answer (score 1):

in my case the problem was due to the new client id naming mode introduced in asp.net 4.0. My site is set to use the new "Predictable" mode, and setting the ListView to "AutoID" did the trick. Try your sample again but with the below property added:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstValues" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
```

Good Luck